# how to handle div tags while using media queries in css?

Tags: css, angular

I am having 1 div tag and I am using media query to render them conditionally as per the scroll size.
I have following css code defined initially.

```
.apple{
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 80px;

}

After using media query it should be @media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .apple{
    width: 100%;     
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:50px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

My issue is that despite specifying the width as 100% I have to scroll horizontally which i want to eliminate.Also why I am getting a horizontal issue when the width is specified as 100% .
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `padding:50px`. If you don't want to remove the padding on the div then add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the class`.apple` in the media query.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're setting the element's (or even the whole DOM) box-sizing to 
`box-sizing: border-box;` , otherwise the `padding` will sum to the element's width and you will end up with a 100% + 100px large element, hence causing a horizontal overflow.